# Import a COM register dll in application in KTM

Tags: c#, dll

I create a dll it contains an entry point. The whole code is working fine. I build the dll, i created a console project that import the reference and so on.

My Issue concerns importing the dll into an application that requires the DLL to be registered as COM. Based on documentation i found, I used Regasm.exe:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "mydll.dll" /tlb /codebase
```

This generates a .tlb file, so far so good. I do also successfully import the tlb. My issue is that even if the dll is correctly found, I can't access to any methods of it.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is a sample of code:

```
namespace mynamespace
{

    public class AppManager
    {

        public Task<SoapResponse> SoapApiCaller(String url, String val1, String val2)
        {
            return Utils.queryResponse(url, val1, val2); 
        }
    }
}
```

my utility class is just making the call. It should be splitted too. but that's not the point;

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class Utils
    {
        public static async Task<SoapResponse> queryResponse(String url, String val1,
            String val2)
        {
            SoapResponse soapResponse= new SoapResponse();
            // check before values
            bool isValid = true;
            var exc = "";
            if (url == null)
            {
                isValid = false;
                exc += "L'url est requise\n";
            }
            if (val1 == null)
            {
                isValid = false;
                exc += "Va\n";
            }
            if (val2 == null)
            {
                isValid = false;
                exc += "val 2 required\n";
            }

            if (!isValid)
            {
                throw new Exception(exc);
            }
            
            // SOAP enveloppe
            string xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> ..."; 
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(xmlStr, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                SoapResponse soapResponse = new SoapResponse();
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
                var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(soapResponse);
                
                if (statusCode == 200)
                {
            
                    var WebServiceFirstResult =
                        document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "WebServiceFirstResult");
                    var WebServiceSecondResult =            
                        document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "WebServiceSecondResult");
                
                    XText xText = (XText)WebServiceSecondResult.FirstNode;
                    

                    var xStr = xText.ToString().Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<");
                    xStr = xStr
                        .Replace("]]>", "")
                        .Replace("<![CDATA[<", "");
            
                    string[] strArr = xStr.Split('<');
            
                    // debugger here !
                    for (var i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // nettoyer autour de "CDATA"
                        Console.WriteLine(strArr[i]);
                        Console.Write("");
                        // on splitte avec >
                        if (strArr[i].Split('>')[0] == "VAL1")
                        {
                            response.VAL1= strArr[i].Split('>')[1];
                        }
                        if (strArr[i].Split('>')[0] == "VAL2")
                        {
                            response.VAL2= strArr[i].Split('>')[1];
                        }
                        if (strArr[i].Split('>')[0] == "VAL3")
                        {
                            response.VAL3 = strArr[i].Split('>')[1];
                        }
                        
                    
                    soapResponse.message = "OK";
                    soapResponse.statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    soapResponse.response= response;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    soapResponse.statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    if (document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "faultstring") != null)
                    { 
                        var errMessageElt = document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "faultstring"); 
                        if (errMessageElt.Value != null) 
                        { 
                            int index = errMessageElt.Value.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }); 
                            string firstline = index == -1 ? errMessageElt.Value : errMessageElt.Value.Substring(0, index);
                            var exceptionMessage = "KO : erreur " + (int)response.StatusCode + " "+ firstline;
                            throw new Exception(exceptionMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("KO : erreur " + (int)response.StatusCode + " " + soapResponse);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
            return soapResponse;

        }
    }
}
```

the assembly information contain the following information:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

It's using .NET Framework 4.8 and c# 8
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjbeP.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3wjq.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVDFM.png

Comment: What actually happens (what's the error that you get)?

Comment: Read following.  You may not need to register if you build app with correct settings.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?force_isolation=true&view=vs-2022#assemblies-tab

Comment: @500-InternalServerError:  Actually i don't get any error. I do register but the application that import the dll sees no methods, it sees at least classes.

Comment: @jdweng: my issue is not to register or not the dll ... it must be registered because the application requires it. the application for which I develop the dll, detects tld files.

Comment: See step 1 2nd parameter : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started?force_isolation=true

Comment: Does the COM assembly target .NET Core?  If so, a different approach to registration may be needed, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Comment: @FrankAlvaro Actually I don't think it's .NET Core.

Comment: @jdweng I don't thinks there's any relation between my issue and Ajax ... I have issue registering a dll ...

Comment: By design.  If you don't want to declare the interface (recommended) then you need the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] attribute on the class you want to expose.

Comment: I just modified my code this way adding annotations... Now i'll have to solve another issue like calling this dll in a VB script :) thanks !!!